# Add up all rows where value is equal to ID

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking up around for a couple tutorials of this and I've seemed out of luck. Basically, I have a database containing a winner's user ID (corresponding to the winners user ID) and a loser's ID. I am trying to create a members profile where it counts up all the rows the member has won. Here is what I have came up with:

```
$web = mysqli_query("select SUM(matches) WHERE WinnerUID='".$req_user_info['id']."'"); 
$web_sum=mysqli_fetch_assoc($web); 
echo $web_sum;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't display any number. Can anyone help?

Comment: any table where these matches are from?

Comment: You're injecting SQL into your code. Magically changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not fix this. Use prepared statements and bound variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `COUNT()` not `SUM()`. And you didn't include a table name. Also remember that `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns the row as an array, it doesn't return the first column's value. Also, `mysqli_query()` requires the connection as the first argument.

```
$web = mysqli_query($conn, "select COUNT(*) as total FROM matches WHERE WinnerUID='".(int)$req_user_info['id']."'"); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($web); 
echo $row['total'];
```

Don't concatenate variables into your SQL. Use a [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with bound parameters. I have casted your ID as an `(int)` in the above code, which is a quick fix but you should switch to a Prepared Statement.

Prepared Statement example (object oriented interface instead of procedural):

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("select COUNT(*) from matches WHERE WinnerUID = ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $req_user_info['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($web_sum);
    $stmt->fetch();

    echo $web_sum;

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Awesome help. I was not even aware that COUNT() existed, but thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. Also added a prepared statement example. `COUNT()` is for counting a number of rows, whereas `SUM()` adds up a field from a number of rows. So `SUM()` is useful for something like adding up the total price of all products that have a `price` field.